# CakePHP 3: Save Associated Model Fail

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm having difficulty using Cakephp 3 patchEntity to save associated models. The models involved are summarized here

My UsersTempTable

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('users_temp');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasOne( 'UsersExtraTemp', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);

}
```

Then my UsersExtraTempTable

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('users_extra_temp');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->belongsTo('UsersTemp', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'UsersTemp'));
        return $rules;
    }
```

Mi function to save the data:

```
   $user = $this->newEntity();
   $user = $this->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
              'associated' => ['UsersTemp.UsersExtraTemp']
           ]);
   $this->save( $user, ['associated' => ['UsersExtraTemp']] );
```

And my array of data print by $this->debug()

```
(
    [name] => name
    [lastname] => lastname
    [email] => email@email.com
    [password] => password
    [passwordConfirm] => repeatPassord
    [UsersExtraTemp] => Array
        (
            [google_token] => sjskdasdadk2
        )

)
```

I get a row created for user_temp in the database but nothing for the one users_extra that I'm expecting. Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: So, `$this` in your saving process is `UsersTempTable`?

Comment: Yes @ndm .. the process to save is the model itself instead of controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `$this` refers to `UsersTempTable`, the `associated` option for `patchEntity()` should not contain that name, as this would suggest that `UsersTempTable` is associated with `UsersTempTable`, which is not the case.

The option should look exactly the same as in the `save()` call, ie

```
$user = $this->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
    'associated' => ['UsersExtraTemp']
]);
```

Also in the data you should use the proper property name for the association, which, in case of a `hasOne` association, is the singular, underscored variant of the association name, ie `users_extra_temp`

```
(
    // ...

    [users_extra_temp] => Array
        (
            [google_token] => sjskdasdadk2
        )

)
```

And last but not least, make sure that the property name is defined in the `UsersTemp` entities `$_accessible` property

```
class UsersTemp extends Entity
{
    // ...

    protected $_accessible = [
        // ...
        'users_extra_temp' => true,
        // ...
    ];

    // ...
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Changing Accessible Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Mass Assignment](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations > HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**